# How to boot-strap a language pair in apertium?

Tags: nlp, apertium

I was following all steps for bootstrapping of existing language pair here http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/How_to_bootstrap_a_new_pair and after following steps when i'm giving command in ubunto terminal
`echo house | apertium -d . eng-spa`
 
it replies me correct answer
`casa`
but when gave command
`echo casa | apertium -d . spa-eng`
it gave me
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'DeserialisationException'
  what():  can't deserialise 1 byte integer type: can't deserialise byte
Aborted (core dumped)`
How can i overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The typical way of debugging these things is to look at the file `modes/spa-eng.mode` and run the pipeline one step at a time until you get the crash.

If the file contained 
`lt-proc spa-eng.automorf.bin | apertium-tagger -g spa-eng.prob | …` and so on, I would first try

```
echo casa | lt-proc spa-eng.automorf.bin
```

then

```
echo casa | lt-proc spa-eng.automorf.bin | apertium-tagger -g spa-eng.prob
```

etc. until I found the crash.

There might be a `$2` as an argument to one of the programs in that file – if so, replace that with `-g`.

Comment: thank you so much your kind answer, yes the problem was in `apertium-tagger -g spa-eng.prob` and when i add -x `apertium-tagger -g -x spa-eng.prob` then it worked fine. but why i had to add this can you please elaborate?

Comment: See `apertium-tagger --help`, it says that `-x` (alternatively `--perceptron`) uses the averaged perceptron algorithm. So your `.prob` file was trained using a perceptron instead of the default (Baum-Welch / Hidden Markov Model stuff)